# Touchscreen interference (metal frame)

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I have one of [these](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?p=1712). It's connected to a raspberry pi. It's being mounted against a metal frame, but when it's mounted, i get interference on the touchscreen (the mouse jumps all over the place). How can I insulate it better. I used 1 layer of duct tape and one layer of electrical tape...but it's still having issues. Any advice?

Comment: What does the metal frame earth to? If not a problem try earthing the frame to 0V on the Pi or preferably 0v on the screen if you can locate it BUT make sure it aint connected to anything else or you might get a meltdown!

Comment: @Andy aka I have a 110 V AC ground line coming in. Can I use that?

Comment: The best solution is that the frame is isolated from anywhere else except the 0V on the display BUT what is the frame - is it connected to elsewhere because if it is then this might be causing interference into the display due to it being close to it. We need detail on what the frame is all about.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. You probabily dont need isolation. This is a common feature when using " Falling Edge"  of your micro controller's external interrupt for touch detection. Just using the " Low Level" interrupt instead of the falling edge solved my problem.

Comment: How can I do this on the RaspberryPi? It's a usb touchscreen. Is there a setting somewhere?